# Passing semaphores as an argument to functions

Tags: c, semaphore, vxworks

I'm working on a static analysis tool which detects if a there's a mismatch for between lock/release calls for a semaphore. The detection is specific to VxWorks RTOS.

I came across this test case

```
void fun(char semid);
char id,i;
int main()
{
    id = semCreate();         //initializing a semaphore
    fun(id);
    semGive(id);              //semaphore release call
    return 0;
}
void fun(char semid)
{
    semTake(semid);          //semaphore lock call
    i++;        
}
```

Logically the code makes sense,we can that for a lock on a semaphore there's a corresponding release too, but is this a correct way of using semaphores? Is this a regular programming practice or is it plainly invalid?

Some detailed code supporting or rejecting the usage of semaphores as given above would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Scattering lock and release calls over different functions is bad style and may leed to a lot of ugly debugging...

Usually you use semaphores like that:

```
SEM_ID semId;

int main()
{
    /* create semaphore */
    semId = semCreate();
    if (semId != NULL)
    {
        /* release semaphore which is initially locked! */
        semGive(semId);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("Failed to create semaphore!\n");
        return (ERROR);
    }

    [...]
}


void someFunction(..)
{
    [...]

    if (semTake(semId) != ERROR)
    {
        /* do something only one thread should do at a time! */

        semGive(semId);
    } /* semTake(semId) */

    [...]
}
```

`semId` could also be passed as parameter: `void someFunction(SEM_ID semId)`.

Comment: So, basically a correct usage is to lock and and release the semaphores in the function itself in which it has been passed as an argument, right?

Comment: @user3917849 Yes. By doing that it is also easy to check if you have the correct number of locks and release calls. There may be special cases in which you have ot separate these calls but I recommend to avoid this.